# Passenger standalone fails to start with capistano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, passenger

I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to deploying and related things, so please be lenient.

I'm building a staging server for a bunch of hobby projects, and to do that, I'll need to

- Support multiple Ruby versions
- Support multiple running rails/other applications
- Support multiple databases and related software

I also want the deploy script to allow deploying to production, if the day ever comes.

This background necessitates the use of RVM, Capistrano-multistage and Passenger Standalone (the other option being Mongrel, but as I wish to use Passenger in production, I figured it'd be safer to use Passenger in staging too). All of this makes deployment a little hairy.

I've gotten things cobbled together quite nicely, and everything else seems to work, but for some reason Passenger fails to start when commanded to do so from Capistrano. If I SSH into the box and type the command in myself it works nicely. What's wrong?

To aid you in your efforts to help me, here is a copy of my config/deploy.rb

```
set :application, "Appname"
set :repository,  "path-to-git-repo-over-ssh"

set :scm, :git

default_run_options[:pty] = true

set :rvm_ruby_string, ENV['GEM_HOME'].gsub(/.*\//,"")
set :rvm_install_ruby_params, '--1.9'      # for jruby/rbx default to 1.9 mode
set :rvm_install_pkgs, %w[libyaml openssl] # package list from https://rvm.io/packages
set :rvm_install_ruby_params, '--with-opt-dir=/usr/local/rvm/usr' # package support
set :use_sudo, false

before 'deploy:setup', 'rvm:install_rvm'   # install RVM
before 'deploy:setup', 'rvm:install_ruby'  # install Ruby and create gemset

require "rvm/capistrano"

require "bundler/capistrano"

require 'sidekiq/capistrano'

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

set :stages, %w(staging production)
set :default_stage, "staging"
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

set :rails_env, lambda { stage }
set :startcmd, lambda { "cd #{current_path} && bundle exec passenger start -d -p #{passenger_port} -e #{rails_env}  --pid-file=#{current_path}/tmp/pids/passenger.#{passenger_port}.pid  #{current_path}" }


namespace :deploy do

  task :stop do
    run("cd #{current_path} && bundle exec passenger stop -p #{passenger_port}")
  end

  task :restart do
    run("cd #{current_path} && touch tmp/restart.txt")
  end

  task :start do
    run("#{startcmd}")
  end
end

after "deploy:update_code" do
  run "(echo \"@reboot /bin/bash -l -c '#{startcmd}' >>log/boot.out 2>>log/boot.err # from capistrano \" && cat #{release_path}/crontab.#{stage}) | crontab -"
end
```

And here is config/deploy/staging.rb

```
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/appname"
set :user, 'app-specific-user'
set :password, 'super-secret-password'
set :domain, '1.2.3.4'
server domain, :app, :web
role :db, domain, :primary => true

set :passenger_port, 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Well bloody hell.
On complete hunch, I removed the

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

Setting from the file, and like magic it started working. Now if only someone would tell me why.

Comment: I took a look at my many variants of deploy files, and they all have this line.  The Brightbox generated file includes the comment, # Forces a Pty so that svn+ssh repository access will work. You
# don't need this if you are using a different SCM system. Note that
# ptys stop shell startup scripts from running.